# Display Message in foreach loop with if else condition

Tags: php, foreach

I want to display error message if condition is false in foreach loop. Here is my code

```
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item['userid'] == logged_in()) {
        echo $item['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'You do not have permission to view items';
    }
}

// other code here needs to continue after loop
```

So with above code the error message display as many time the loop runs. So if there is 5 items than message display for 5 times. While I want to display only one time if condition is false. I have tried with `break;` and `continue;` but both stop executing further php code.

```
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item['userid'] == logged_in()) {
        echo $item['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'You do not have permission to view items';
        break; // or continue
    }
}

// other code here needs to continue after loop
```

So what can I do to display this message only one and further code also will execute?

Comment: break will break the loop after displaying the message and this should you do.

Comment: what is inside `logged_in()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this-

```
$once=false;
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item['userid'] == logged_in()) {
        echo $item['title'];
    } else {             
       $once=true;
    }
}

if($once)
   echo 'You do not have permission to view items';
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to break or continue, because you want to keep testing each item in the loop. Instead mark the error and continue looping:

```
$permissionError = 0;
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item['userid'] == logged_in()) {
        echo $item['title'];
    } else {
        $permissionError = 1;
    }
}
if($permissionError) {
    echo 'You do not have permission to view all items';
}
```